# Angular - ng-change checkbox doesn't fire for first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I want to fire *ng-change* whenever user change checkbox's status. Here is my code :

```
                    <div ng-class=" food.status == 1 ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger'" class="pull-left m-t-sm ">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                        <label class="md-switch">
                            --{{ food.status }}
                            **{{ food.enableFood }}
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="food.enableFood"  ng-model="food.status" ng-change="changeFoodStatus(food.status , food.id)">
                            <i class="blue"></i>
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

And here is my Angular function :

```
$scope.changeFoodStatus = function (status , id) {
    console.log(status,id);
    var foodStatus = 1 ;
    if(!status) {
        foodStatus = 2;
    }
    console.log(foodStatus , id);
    var foodData = {
        foodStatus  : foodStatus,
        foodId      : id
    };



    Gateway.put( foodData , '/food/changeFoodStatus',function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Here is my initial output :

[image]

It works like a charm after first time , Actually it doesn't work at first time when *food.enableFood* is true . `ng-change` doesn't fire.

How to resolve it?

Comment: are you initializing food.enableFood? Also, what happens if you change ng-change to ng-click? Does the function fire?

Comment: Yes I initialize food.enableFood , I've changed it to ng-click and it fired but its behavior is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I've changed my html to :

```
                    <div ng-class=" food.status == 1 ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger'" class="pull-left m-t-sm ">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                        <label class="md-switch">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="2" ng-model="food.status" ng-change="changeFoodStatus(food.status , food.id)">
                            <i class="blue"></i>
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

p.s. Thanks @holtc.